# How to create data attribute with underline instead of dashes with Html.Helper?

Tags: html, .net, razor, jquery-chosen

i have seen some questions about that problem when creating data attributes with dashes in a razor page ex:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty, new { data-bind="something" })
```

and the answer is using underline (_) instead of dashes like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty, new { data_bind="something" })
```

and the HTML output would be something like:

```
<input name="someProperty" data-bind="something"/>
```

But my question is how to make razor create a html data attribute with underline and still using `Html.Helper`? the desirable output is something like:

```
<input name="someProperty" data_bind="something"/>
```

I am using a JQuery plugin ([chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen)) that requires data-attributes with underline, not dashes.